# NAN in timeinterval

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

I am getting nan in timeiterval . I am counting time interval from server date and current date . Was working fine. But I got nan instead of time interval . In some object I am getting nan and in some object it is returning right interval.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"today %@",date);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *dt = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dt %@",dt);

NSDate *convertedDate = [df dateFromString:dt];
NSLog(@"cnvrt %@",convertedDate);

NSString *date1 = [ObjectDict valueForKey:@"time"];
NSLog(@"%@",date1);
NSTimeInterval commnetInterval = [convertedDate timeIntervalSinceDate:[df dateFromString:date1]];
NSLog(@"%f timeinterval",commnetInterval);


float minutes = commnetInterval / 60.0;
float hours = minutes / 60.00;
float days = minutes / 1440.0;

NSLog(@"days %f\n hours %f\n min %f",days,hours,minutes);
```

Here is my log:

```
cnvrt 2014-03-06 03:46:42 +0000//current date
2014-03-06 09:16:42.417 BeachImageApplication[2848:a0b] 2014-03-04 16:08:23// date from server
2014-03-06 09:16:42.418 BeachImageApplication[2848:a0b] nan timeinterval
2014-03-06 09:16:42.418 BeachImageApplication[2848:a0b] days nan
hours nan
min nan
```

Comment: Are you sure `[df dateFromString:date1]` returns a valid `NSDate`? What is its value?

Comment: Why are you converting [NSDate date] into String dt and then converting String dt into NSDate convertedDate?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is twofold.

1. Your date format needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`, not `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`.
2. Using the wrong format is causing `[df dateFromString:date1]` to return `nil`. And passing `nil` to `timeIntervalSinceDate:` results in `commnetInterval` being `Nan`.

Once you fix the date format, the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting the date with wrong date Format. It should be

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```